# Limiting numbers to a maximum value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a built-in function or some other way to limit the value of numbers in MySQL?

For example, let's say I have a table with the following rows:

```
score
=====
5
10
20
50
3
15
```

I'd looking for some type of query along the lines of...

```
SELECT NUMBER_LIMITER(score, 10) FROM ScoresTable
```

...which would return the following result...

```
score
=====
5
10
10
10
3
10
```

If not, I'll write a function.  Just hoping there might be something built-in as performance is quite important for this project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT LEAST(score, 10) FROM ScoresTable
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least

Comment: Awesome thanks!  This is one of those things where a bunch of google searches came up with nothing because I wasn't using the right terms.  Never thought to look in the comparison section of the manual.